# Mathjax displays math formula as normal text in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: reactjs, mathjax

One of the user reported an issue that math formulas are not displaying correctly. I checked that he is using Microsoft Edge browser. What will be the cause for this and any workaround for it.

In Microsoft Edge
[image]

In Chrome
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We strongly suggest to follow Microsoft’s suggestion to use `IE=edge`. That is, in the document `<head>` include

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

before any other tags in the . This will force all IE versions to use their latest engine which is the optimal setting for [mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax).